# Bloch Sphere of Qiskit logo

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, bloch-sphere

Trying to plot the Bloch Sphere of the IBM Qiskit logo

```
from qiskit import execute, Aer, IBMQ, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.visualization import plot_state_qsphere, plot_bloch_multivector
%matplotlib inline

# no. of qubits
n = 4

# create circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(n)

# apply hadamard
qc.h(0)

# apply cnot
for i in range(n-1):
    qc.cx(0, i+1)

# apply not on q1
qc.x(1)

# get state vector
sv = Statevector.from_instruction(qc).data

# plots
plot_state_qsphere(sv)
plot_bloch_multivector(sv)
```

[image]

Why the Bloch Sphere does not have any state representations?

Circuit [link](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer/files/new?initial=N4IgdghgtgpiBcICKBLAzgaxQFwPoBsB7Ac0JABoQBHCNKBEAeQAUBRAOSQEEBlAWQAEAJgB0ABgDcAHTAowAY3wBXACYwBU6jHwoARgEYRc%2BZulgZVAE4xiAqgG0AzAF0z867fn2hrmTIAWdvZivgoAHkEh5A76ofIRDlEOPmYJ9rESFCBqaO4oAA7YKIRgDCAAvkA)

Comment: The logo is a Qsphere not a Bloch sphere. The former is a multi Qubit statevector visualization whereas the latter is for single qubits.

Comment: @PaulNation Thanks. `plot_bloch_multivector` is for visualizing the individual qubits. It works for other circuits. What am I missing here?

Comment: If each qubit is maximally entangled with the others then the bloch cector has zero length. Try a bell state for example.

Comment: @PaulNation that explains it! Cheers!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As @PaulNation explained](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16734/bloch-sphere-of-qiskit-logo/16739#comment24534_16734), the bloch spheres represent maximally entangled qubits as zero-length vectors. Hence, no arrows.

The Qiskit logo is a qsphere of a particular statevector. In particular, a 6-qubit state, [according to Abe](https://twitter.com/abe_asfaw/status/1252545138188079104):

```
from qiskit.visualization import plot_state_qsphere
state = [0]*2**6
state[2] = 1; state[61] = 1
plot_state_qsphere(state, show_state_labels=False)
```

[image: qiskit logo qsphere]

So... you are actually really really close. Just change `n = 6` I you will get it!

Here is your fixed code:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
from qiskit.visualization import plot_state_qsphere

n = 6
qc = QuantumCircuit(n)
qc.h(0)
for i in range(n-1):
    qc.cx(0, i+1)
qc.x(1)

sv = Statevector.from_instruction(qc)
plot_state_qsphere(sv, show_state_labels=False)
```

[image: qiskit logo qsphere]

To increase the similarity, delete the legend and modify the elevation:

```
fig = plot_state_qsphere(sv, show_state_labels=False)
fig.axes[0].view_init(elev=11, azim=275)
fig.axes[1].set_visible(False)
fig
```

[image]

Comment: do qiskit logo have any special meaning, where is it come from?

Answer (score -1):

Apply these gates in order:

```
circuit=QuantumCircuit(4)
circuit.h(1)
circuit.cx(1,0)
circuit.cx(1,2)
circuit.cx(1,3)
circuit.x(1)
```